# Getting the userID of a logged in User in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can I get the exact ID of a user that is logged into a site?

I'm using the login and registration controls created by Visual Studio 2010, in the database the unique identifier is in this `28e8957e-00b8-4e75-bec9-2b90e640962d` for example how can I return the exact one to be used in an SQL command for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
using System.Web.Security;

Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: +1, also the overload that doesn't take any parameters: [`Membership.GetUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcxcb339.aspx), if it is ok to update the last activity date while doing this.